# mvc html.serialize to store model in view

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

Can anyone tell me what happened to the Html.Serialize function mentioned in the url below.

It's not recognized when I try and use it in a MVC2 web app within Visual Studio 2010.

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx

EDIT - I'm using visual studio 2010 which comes with mvc2 'built in' when i try and use Html.serialize on a view or partial view it's not appearing in intellisense. Am i missing a reference or something?

Comment: I cracked it, see my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't gone anywhere.  It is right there, wherever you are able to use the html extensions.  Eg, Views, PartialViews.

For example:

```
<%= Html.Serialize("wizardData", Model)%>
```

Are you trying to use it in a controller?  To use it as shown in the article you quote, you need to use it in a view.

You see, we really don't know because you haven't given us any detail to work with.  Show us some code, and we will move your earth.  Well, try to anyway.

I see you are new, so when asking questions, try to give as much detail as possible.  You can edit your post, just mark out what you have done.  The more context we get, the more we can help.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010 which comes with mvc2 'built in' when i try and use Html.serialize on a view or partial view it's not appearing in intellisense.  Am i missing a reference or something?

Comment: This answer is plain wrong.  It's in the MVCFutures and not part of the out the box MVC framework.  You will need to add the package via nuget and then add a using statement to Microsoft.Web.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

I found out why! I was having similar problems too.

You need to download [ASP.NET 2 Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742#DownloadId=110348) and use the DLLs provided there instead of the usual Mvc DLL.

It is implemented in `SerializationExtensions` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the MVCFutures assembly and not part of the out the box MVC framework. You will need to add the package via nuget or manual download and then add a using/imports statement to Microsoft.Web.Mvc before you can use it in your view.